# How can I get more debugging info about the Symfony2 security system?

Tags: security, symfony, debugging

In general, how can I get useful debugging output about the decisions made by the various components of the Symfony2 security system during request processing?  I would love to see things like what firewall and access_control statements were applied and why.  What tools are there to make it easier to address the perennial "Why did I get redirected to the login form again" mystery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Blackfire](http://symfony.com/marketplace/development-tools/blackfire) if you need detailed debug information.

If its not sufficient then you can use [WebProfilerBundle](http://qpleple.com/webprofilerbundleextra-a-must-have-tool-for-symfony2-developers/) it has good debugging information.

If that also not work for you then you can create your own Data Collector Services.
Data Collectors are just like profiler extensions and they can help you to collect different data like routes, debug information or mailer data also. You can customize them according to your need.

Please check the documentation [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html)

Please check [SecurityDebugBundle](https://github.com/egulias/SecurityDebugCommandBundle) This will answer your all questions.
Use it carefully, as it requires different permissions.

By Reading its code you will understand how Data Collectors can help you out in debugging.

Hope that will help you.

Here is the DataCollecotr from SecurityDebugBundle:

```
class FirewallCollector
{
    const HAS_RESPONSE = SecurityDebugDataCollector::DENIED;
    private $securityContext;
    private $container;
    public function __construct(
        SecurityContextInterface $securityContext,
        Container $container
    ) {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        //Container dependency is a bad thing. This is to be refactored to a compiler pass
        //where all the firewall providers will be fetched
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    public function collect(Request $request, \Exception $exception)
    {
        $token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
        if (!method_exists($token, 'getProviderKey')) {
            return;
        }
        $providerKey = $token->getProviderKey();
        $map = $this->container->get('security.firewall.map.context.' . $providerKey);
        $firewallContext = $map->getContext();
        $event = new GetResponseEvent(
            new SimpleHttpKernel(),
            $request,
            HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST
        );
        $firewalls = array();
        foreach ($firewallContext[0] as $i => $listener) {
            $firewalls[$i]= array('class' => get_class($listener), 'result' => SecurityDebugDataCollector::GRANTED);
            try {
                $listener->handle($event);
            } catch (AccessDeniedException $ade) {
                $firewalls[$i]['result'] = SecurityDebugDataCollector::DENIED;
                break;
            }
            if ($event->hasResponse()) {
                $firewalls[$i]['result'] = self::HAS_RESPONSE;
                break;
            }
        }
        return $firewalls;
    }
}
```

This gives alot information on Firewall.
This Bundle Also contains [SecurityDebugDataCollector](https://github.com/egulias/SecurityDebugCommandBundle/blob/master/DataCollector/SecurityDebugDataCollector.php) and [VotersCollector](https://github.com/egulias/SecurityDebugCommandBundle/blob/master/DataCollector/VotersCollector.php). So it can give information on all security components.

Comment: Blackfire is a profiler - how would it add in debugging the security component?  WebProfilerBundle doesn't seem to display any information related to security.  I don't quite see how a DataCollector could be used to gather debug information about the security component - can you expand on that a bit?

Comment: @astletron If you find the answer correct please accept it, or if you have any other solution please post here.